# Rename a column in a table with SQL Sserver 2008

Tags: sql-server

I have read through all the answers for this question and none (that I have found) answers my question.

Can I rename a column using the column number?

I have a table that may have already had a column name changed, so I may not know what it is to "hard code" it. Can I reference the column by number, something like this...

```
EXEC sp_rename '[ChkLst].column7', 'NewColName', 'COLUMN'"
```

Thanks

Comment: Thank you Sami, forgot to put code in blocks.

Comment: Is column7 the name of the column or the column position? If it is the latter you'd want to query a system table to get the column name and then pass that as a variable or if the sp_rename doesn't take variables use dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the current column name from `SYS.COLUMNS` using the table name and column ID, then execute `SP_RENAME` as below.  Note that the column IDs are **NOT** guaranteed to be sequential and that you should confirm the ID of the column before attempting to rename it.

```
DECLARE @ColumnName VARCHAR(50);

SET @ColumnName = 'YourSchema.YourTable.';

SET @ColumnName = CONCAT(@ColumnName, 
(SELECT name FROM SYS.COLUMNS WHERE OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID(N'YourTable') AND column_id = 7));

EXEC SP_RENAME @ColumnName, 'NewColumnName', 'COLUMN';
```

Comment: Works like a champ. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you know column number (ordinal position), you can get column name by running following query:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM Information_Schema.Columns
WHERE TABLE_NAME = '<TableName>' AND ORDINAL_POSITION = <ColumnNumber>
```

and you can use the column name using following query:

```
DECLARE @ColName nvarchar(100)

SELECT @ColName = COLUMN_NAME FROM Information_Schema.Columns
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TableName' AND ORDINAL_POSITION = 2

SET @ColName = 'TableName.[' + @ColName + ']'

sp_RENAME @ColName , '[NewColumnName]', 'COLUMN'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like

```
DECLARE @SchemaTable VARCHAR(50),
        @NewName VARCHAR(50) = 'MyColumn';

SELECT @SchemaTable = 
           CONCAT(S.name, '.', T.name, '.', COL_NAME(T.object_id, 2))
FROM Sys.Tables T INNER JOIN Sys.Schemas S
          ON T.schema_id = S.schema_id
WHERE T.name = 'YourTableName' 
      AND
      T.type = 'U';

EXEC sp_rename @SchemaTable, @NewName, 'COLUMN';
```